# Generic function pointer inside struct with compile time validation

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have header file **String.h**

```
typedef struct String String;
typedef String* String_t;
...
struct String {
    //... other methods
    void (*push_str)(String_t self, void *str); ??? 
}

void string_push_cstr(String_t self, char * str);
void string_push_slice(String_t self, Slice_t str);
void string_push_string(String_t self, String_t str);

#define string_push_str(self, str) _Generic(str, \
    char*: string_push_cstr, \
    String_t: string_push_string, \
    Slice_t: string_push_slice \
)(self, str);
```

Is it possible somehow to add such a generic push_str function to my String struct with same API and compile time validation? (No Union types, or additional arguments)

My closest try was using such cringey hack

```
#define push_str(self, str) dummy();_Generic(str, \
    char*: string_push_cstr, \
    String_t: string_push_string, \
    Slice_t: string_push_slice \
)(self, str);
```

dummy was basically a **nop** function pointer inside String struct
so after preprocessing i was doing the same thing but with extra empty invocation

Comment: Why have only _one_ function pointer in `String` when you want to accept 3 different types? Add one function pointer per type you need to deal with. ... but I don't see why you need function pointers in your `String` anyway. The `_Generic` will direct the call to the proper `string_push_*` function.

Comment: Don't hide pointers behind `typedef`s.  Hiding what something is makes reading and understanding code **harder**.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it's just a preference)) I wanted to try implementing something like static polymorhism/overloading inside a struct

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm new to C, I wanted to create a custom smart pointer

Comment: @u23r _"static polymorhism/overloading inside a struct"_ - I would understand _runtime_ polymorphism since you could change the function pointers at runtime. In that case you'd need one per "overload" as I mentioned.

Comment: @TedLyngmo but in first case using _Generic macro isn't it doing all the computations during compile time making it static?

Comment: @u23r Yes, so for that you don't need the function pointers in `String`. For _runtime_ polymorphism, you could use function pointers in `String` - but not one, but just as many as you have in the `_Generic`.

Comment: Someone tries to reinvent the wheel. XY problem. Runtime polymorphism is not needed here as your struct always holds your string.

Comment: @0___________ "Reinventing the wheel" --> Perhaps a good thing now and then, else we would use [chariot wheels](https://scroll.in/reel/814276/no-ben-hur-adaptation-is-complete-without-a-chariot-race-sequence) or [Fred's wheels](https://gigazine.net/gsc_news/en/20110722_fred_flintstones_car/). 

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica but it is good to see what other people have done so far...

Comment: Please add a [mre] of the intended usage. You are mentioning "_smart pointer_", how does this match the overload mechanism you show?

Comment: You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers). Also note that types ending in `_t` are reserved for future language expansion. (though I can't say I never violate that one...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "Also note that types ending in _t are reserved for future language expansion" Not really. The C standard only says that such types may get added to the  `stdint.h` header. You might confuse this with POSIX which does ban the use of `_t`, but that's just a problem with the badly designed POSIX standard. POSIX is broken in numerous other ways too, to the point where it might not be possible to fix it without starting over. For example it assumes that non-standard identifiers may be placed in C standard library headers, which was never the case.

Comment: @Lundin it is a POSIX reservation, sorry, should have been more clear.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yeah but disobeying POSIX is a minor thing, compared to disobeying the C standard. Kind of like if you smoke indoors in a restaurant in a country where this is forbidden by law, you might get dragged away by the police. But if you smoke in the designated smoking area which has been designated for such in ages, and some random person not affiliated with the restaurant comes and put up a "no smoking allowed" sign in that area, you can freely ignore it - it was just a random vandal with no authority to put themselves above the law or the owner of the restaurant.

Comment: Chuckling -- that's an apt analogy. Glad I was never a smoker faced with the choice -- I'd a likely just lit up `:)`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would strongly recommend following this advice:

- Keep the struct internals private by implementing an "opaque type". Check out [How to do private encapsulation in C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283888)
- Never hide pointers behind typedef, not even for "opaque types". It is simply error prone and unreadable - countless of attempts have been made before you, countless attempts have failed. You can research all criticism against the Windows API type system as one example.
- Do not attempt member functions inside a struct by means of a function pointer. This is a plain awkward interface since you have to pass a pointer to the struct itself along anyway.

  The linked post addresses this issue too:

  > Regarding member functions:
  >
  > Note that in this example, member functions are declared in the header rather than as function pointers in a public part of the struct. Some like to use function pointers to emulate C++-like member syntax like `obj.member()` (see for example *Schreiner - Object-oriented Programming in ANSI-C*, a book which I don't really recommend), but I think that's a rather pointless feature.
  >
  > In C, there are no automatic constructor/destructor calls, no RAII, no `this` pointers. Meaning you have to pass along a reference to the object anyway.
  >
  > So rather than writing `foo.bar(&foo, stuff)` you might as well write `bar(&foo, stuff)`. But name `bar` something meaningful so it becomes clear which class it belongs to. In my example above, everything belonging to the `cstring` class is prefixed with `cstring`.
  >
  > Also, declaring function pointers in the struct itself means that those are allocated for every instance of the class. That's potentially wasting a lot of memory.

---

That being said - to answer the question as-is, without heading the advise above (not recommending to ignore it, obviously):

Your dummy example wasn't far from a working program. Essentially the `void (*push_str)(String_t self, void *str)` *is* the dummy function since you don't really expect this to ever accept a `void*` now do you? Actually the parameter types don't matter in the method used below:

With a slight rewrite you can do this:

```c
#define push_str(self, str) push_str,     \
  _Generic((str),                         \
           char*:    string_push_cstr,    \
           String_t: string_push_string   \
)(self, str)
```

- The `push_str` macro name will replace the calling code `obj.push_str(...)` with the macro, so you don't actually call the function pointer member function here. Instead you call two member functions located outside the struct (where they ought to be, see my previous remarks).
- `push_str,` in the macro is however the member function pointer followed by a comma operator. Meaning that the macro will expand the caller code to `obj.push_str, string_push_cstr(/* args */)` where `obj.push_str` is a dummy no-op, it is not calling the function, just using the function pointer itself as an expression.

  Yeah this is kind of a dirty hack too and not without problems of operator precedence etc. But it will actually result in an expression returning whatever `string_push_cstr` returns, if anything.
- Note the lack of semicolon at the end of the macro. Which is standard procedure when writing function-like macros.

Here's an updated, simplified example using your original code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct String String;
typedef String* String_t;

struct String {
    char str[50];
    void (*push_str)(String_t self, void *str);
};

void string_push_cstr(String_t self, char * str)
{
  strcpy(self->str, str);
}

void string_push_string(String_t self, String_t str)
{
  *self = *str;
}

#define push_str(self, str) push_str,     \
  _Generic((str),                         \
           char*:    string_push_cstr,    \
           String_t: string_push_string   \
)(self, str)


int main (void)
{
  String s1 = { .str = "hello " };
  String s2;

  s2.push_str(&s2, &s1);
  puts(s2.str);
  
  s2.push_str(&s2, "world");
  puts(s2.str);
}
```

Output:

```
hello 
world
```

Answer (score 0):

You would:

- convert all specific types to an abstract type
- work on that generic type to do the task

The "generic type" in this case is easy to find in other languages - it is an "iterator" or a "range". Then, the containers work using those iterators. In the world of C++ inserting an iterator to a container is done with [`std::string::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert). In the world of Rust there is [std::iter::Extend](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html#tymethod.extend).

So you could:

```
typedef struct Iterator Iterator_t;
struct Iterator {
   // forward sequential iterator - only advances forward one by one
   // EOF on end
   int (*next)(Iterator_t *self);
   void *data;
};
static int _iterator_cstr_next(Iterator_t *self) {
    const char *str = self->data;
    return str ? *(str++) : EOF;
}        
Iterator_t iterator_from_cstr(const char *str) {
     return (Iterator_t){
         next = _iterator_cstr_next,
         data = str,
     };
}
void iterator_for_each(Iterator_t *self, void (*cb)(void *cookie, char c), void *cookie) {
     for (int c; (c = self->next(self)) != EOF; ) {
          cb(cookie, c);
     }
}

Iterator_t string_to_iterator(String_t *self);
void string_insert(String_t *self, Iterator_t *it);

Iterator_t slice_to_iterator(Slice_t *self);
void slice_back_inserter_void(void *self, char c);

int main() {
    String_t some_string;
    Iterator_t some_string_it = string_to_iterator(&some_string);
    String_t some_other_string;
    string_insert(&some_string, &some_string_it);
}
```

Now how to exactly model it, if you want to have a "range" object representing start and end, or you want to have just forward iterator like in the example above, depends on the specific operations *you* want to model.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to write with these 3 functions, but I will show you a toy example with code and output, and write some arguments on the subject.

`C` language:

- has no `class` like other languages, so no `instance` of class
- has no methods in the sense of `java` or `C++`
- has no `private` data in `struct`
- has no `#values` like in `javascript` classes
- has no `this` pointer in `struct`
- has `void*,` and a `void**` `NULL` terminated array can do a lot of polymorphic stuff
- is not `C++`, not even close.
- is a workhorse.

#### A `C` *"class"*

If you want to see `String` like a class, with all limitations,  you can use an array of function pointers, and do some *normalization* in the function signatures. `void*` returning functions that take a `void**` argument `NULL` terminated would be hard to read and mantain, but is possible.

If the function signatures are different then the array idea is gone...

As a minimum of methods we need, in OOP terms:

- a *constructor* that returns a new `String`
- a *destructor* that frees all allocated stuff
- a *copy constructor*  would be handy to return a fresh copy of a `String`
- a *`toString()`* method like in `java`, that prints out a `String` so we can test at ease

And I will write a few extras:

- a *`slice()`* method like the one in *javascript array class* that, well, returns a slice of the original `String`.
- an *`empty()`*  method that returns `0` if the string is empty.

#### a `struct` for `String`

Consider this

```
typedef struct st_S String;
typedef struct st_S
{
    size_t  size;  // size
    char*   S;     // the array
    String* (*destroy)(String*);
    String* (*copy)(const String*);
    String* (*slice)(const String*, unsigned, unsigned);
    int     (*show)(const String*, const char*);
    int     (*empty)(const String*);
    void** elements;
} String;
```

All methods use a `String*` since we have no `this` pointer in `C`. It can sure break things since the code can not assure that the pointers refer to the same instance of `String`.

Anyway, for this one we can declare a constructor like

```
String* so_create(
    const char* source, String* destroy(String*),
    String* copy(const String*),
    String* slice(const String*, unsigned, unsigned),
    int     show(const String*, const char*),
    int     empty(const String*));
```

And write one or more implementions of the other methods.

#### `main.c` testing this methods on `String`

So, if we write this mehods then this code for `main` should work (and call all methods):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stuff.h"
int main(void)
{
    String* one = so_create(
        "Stack Overflow", so_destroy, so_copy, so_slice,
        so_show, so_empty);
    if (one == NULL)
    {   fprintf(stderr, "    Error creating string\n");
        return -1; }

    one->show(one, NULL);
    String* other = one->copy(one);
    one->show(other, "A simple copy     ");
    other = other->destroy(other);

    other = one->slice(one, 1, 14);
    other->show(other, "slice(1,14)       ");
    other = other->destroy(other);

    other = one->slice(one, 0, 1);
    other->show(other, "slice(0, 1)       ");

    if (other->empty(other))
        printf("Previous slice was empty\n");
    else
        printf(
            "Previous slice was not empty: size is %llu\n",
            other->size);
    other = other->destroy(other);

    one = one->destroy(one);
    return 0;
}
```

Notes on the code:

- `slice(a,b)` is like in `javascript` arrays and returns an open ended substring of the original, from index `a` up to but not including `b`. I did not implement it for negative values.
- `show` accpets an optional prefix to help in testing, so no need for messy `printf` calls.
- `destroy` returns `NULL` and is used to invalidate the `String` pointer in the same line.

#### the output

```
    [15] "Stack Overflow"
A simple copy         [15] "Stack Overflow"
slice(1,14)           [14] "tack Overflow"
slice(0, 1)           [2] "S"
Previous slice was not empty: size is 2
```

#### stuff.h: the header

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct st_S String;
typedef struct st_S
{
    size_t  size;  // size
    char*   S;     // the array
    String* (*destroy)(String*);
    String* (*copy)(const String*);
    String* (*slice)(const String*, unsigned, unsigned);
    int     (*show)(const String*, const char*);
    int     (*empty)(const String*);
    void** elements;
} String;

String* so_create(
    const char* org, String* destroy(String*),
    String* copy(const String*),
    String* slice(const String*, unsigned, unsigned),
    int     show(const String*, const char*),
    int     empty(const String*));

String* so_copy(const String*);
String* so_destroy(String*);
int     so_empty(const String*);
int     so_show(const String*, const char*);
String* so_slice(const String*, unsigned, unsigned);
int     so_empty(const String*);
```

#### stuff.c: a possible implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stuff.h"

String* so_destroy(String* this)
{
    if (this == NULL) return NULL;
    if (this->S != NULL) free(this->S);
    free(this);
    return NULL;
}

int so_empty(const String* this) { return this->size == 0; }

int so_show(const String* this, const char* prefix)
{
    if (this == NULL) return -1;
    if (prefix != NULL) printf("%s", prefix);
    printf("    [%llu] \"%s\"\n", this->size, this->S);
    return 0;
}

String* so_create(
    const char* src, String* destroy(String*),
    String* copy(const String*),
    String* slice(const String*,unsigned,unsigned),
    int     show(const String*, const char*),
    int     empty(const String*))
{
    String* nw = malloc(sizeof(String));
    if (nw == NULL) return NULL;
    if (src == NULL)
    {
        nw->size = 0;
        nw->S    = NULL;
        return nw;
    }
    nw->size = 1+strlen(src);
    nw->S    = malloc(nw->size);
    if (nw->S == NULL)
    {
        free(nw);
        return NULL;
    }
    char* dst = nw->S;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nw->size; i += 1)
        *dst++ = *src++;
    nw->destroy = destroy;
    nw->copy    = copy;
    nw->slice   = slice;
    nw->show    = show;
    nw->empty   = empty;
    return nw;
}

String* so_copy(const String* this)
{
    if (this == NULL) return NULL;
    return so_create(
        this->S, this->destroy, this->copy, this->slice,
        this->show, this->empty);
}

String* so_slice(const String* this, unsigned start, unsigned end)
{
    if (this == NULL) return NULL;
    if (end <= start) return NULL;
    if (end > this->size - 1)
        return so_create(
            NULL, this->destroy, this->copy, this->slice,
            this->show, this->empty);
    size_t sz = end - start; // size of slice
    char   tmp = *(this->S+end); 
    *( (this->S) + end ) = 0;
    String* copy = so_create(
        (this->S)+start, this->destroy, this->copy, this->slice,
        this->show, this->empty);
    *((this->S) + end) = tmp;
    return copy;
}
```

This can have some forms of polymorphism since we can provide many implementations for any method except `create()`.

But it is just a toy. Hope it helps in some way.

Comment: "has no class like other languages, so no instance of class" Achievable with opaque type. "has no private data in struct" Achievable with opaque type. "has no this pointer in struct" You get this indirectly while implementing opaque types. [How to do private encapsulation in C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283888/283890)

Comment: Furthermore, implementing member functions through function pointers might make C "feel" more like C++ since you can use the `obj.member()` syntax, but it's actually quite cumbersome since you end up allocating the function pointers inside each and every object. And then you must leave the struct public also. C++ solves with with vtables and so should you in C. That is: do _not_ expose the internals of the struct to the caller but instead make a `static` function pointer table in the C file which is then used by the public functions of that file. You won't get `obj.member()` syntax though.

Comment: I did it intentionally, to preserve the ' C++' feeling, as you told :). I wrote briefly about a VFT and a NULL terminated array of pointers in the args, for an example. But it is just it: an example. And I believe that a few pointers are not a huge waste of memory

Comment: Regarding the function pointers it's not just a memory concern (which is also real in case or large arrays), but also compilers are notoriously poor at inlining function calls done through function pointers - it is very hard for them to do so. Lots of member functions will just be plain setter/getters. You'll want those to be inlined when possible not to bloat up the program needlessly. If you end up writing C code performing equally poor or even worse than C++ code, you might as well code in C++.

Comment: `other = one->slice(one, 1, 14);` Changing `14` to `32` (because it's _boring_ to count characters) the executable crashes... Changing `1` to `30` also causes the program to crash. `so_show()` doesn't protect itself from **following the NULL pointer** regarding the string it prints. AND, in `so_slice()`, `if (end > this->size - 1)` wants to refer to `start`, not `end`... Software professionals normally **test** their programs...

Comment: :) I did not test. Just like that. I just wanted to have `slice()`  like in the original code. And I did not wrote code for negative indexes also, but lazily changed the indexes to unsigned. This is just an example on a way to put the functions inside the `struct`, not _professional_  software. If I change it I promise to add some tests. Even for `malloc` calls!

Comment: @arfneto "_If I change it..._" Meaning that you're not going to fix its bugs...

Comment: In this case, yes. It is not relevant. A _mock up_ it is. If I decide to implement the rest of `slice` I can _fix_  it.